# Gitlab CI : generating javaScript bundles failed. During build - GitLab CI + AWS s3, cloudfront, gatsby.js

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gatsby

After configuring AWS and gitLab, the page deploy successfully but I'm getting the following error after each commit. What could be the cause of this problem ? below is my gitlab-ci.yml and an error.

```
image: docker:latest

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

build:
  stage: build
  image: node:8.11.3
  script:
      - export API_URL="https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/"
      - npm install
      - npm run build
      - echo "BUILD SUCCESSFULLY"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public/
    expire_in: 20 mins
  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:3.5
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
    - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=kC0DF4gdVhB2Oahxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1
    - export S3_BUCKET_NAME=s3://name-s3s3s3
    #- export DISTRIBUTION_ID=$DISTRIBUTION_ID
    - pip install awscli --upgrade --user
    - export PATH=~/.local/bin:$PATH
    - aws s3 sync --acl public-read --delete public $S3_BUCKET_NAME
    #- aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id $DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*'
    - echo "DEPLOYED SUCCESSFULLY"

  environment:
    name: production
  only:
    - master
```

[image]

[image]